# Exporting datagridview and label vaue to excel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a datagridview which contains bill details. And also a label which contains the total amount. I want to add the datagridview values to excel and the total from label at the end of the datagridview values in excel.

here im using a function to export datagridview to excel. and calling it in a click event.

```
      private void ToCsV(DataGridView dGV, string filename)
    {
        string stOutput = "";
        // Export titles:
        string sHeaders = "";

        for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Columns.Count; j++)
            sHeaders = sHeaders.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[j].HeaderText) + "\t";
        stOutput += sHeaders + "\r\n";
        // Export data.
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            string stLine = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < dGV.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                stLine = stLine.ToString() + Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value) + "\t";
            stOutput += stLine + "\r\n";
        }
        Encoding utf16 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1254);
        byte[] output = utf16.GetBytes(stOutput);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
        bw.Write(output, 0, output.Length); //write the encoded file
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Now i want to add the label value which is total to the end of excel data. I have seen examples to add label values. But my problem is i want to add it at the end of data in excel. So it can be referred as total.  How can i do that. Im stuck with it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Hmm… `stOutput += myLabel.Text + “\r\n”;` once you exit the loop make the labels text the last line?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your datagridview is being populated from `DataTable`. You can use `EPPlus` library which is opensource. Download it from web and refer in your application. Here is the code..

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" +   HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Logs.xlsx", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Logs");
ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);    

 //Here you can add your Label value to whatever cells you want..for example- A1 or something

var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
pck.SaveAs(ms);
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);                          
}
```